# decodeHexString obj-c implementation, Should I support odd lengthed hexstrings, and if so, how?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring, hex

I may be missing something in the standard libs, but I don't think so.  I have this current implementation:

```
int char2hex(unsigned char c) {
    switch (c) {
        case '0' ... '9': 
            return c - '0';
        case 'a' ... 'f': 
            return c - 'a' + 10;
        case 'A' ... 'F': 
            return c - 'A' + 10;
        default: 
            WARNING(@"passed non-hexdigit (%s) to hexDigitToInt()", c);
            return 0xFF;
    }
}

- (NSData *)decodeHexString {
    ASSERT([self length] % 2, @"Attempted to decode an odd lengthed hex string.");

    NSData *hexData = [self dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSMutableData *resultData = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:([hexData length]) / 2];

    const unsigned char *hexBytes = [hexData bytes];
    unsigned char *resultBytes = [resultData mutableBytes];

    for(NSUInteger i = 0; i < [hexData length] / 2; i++) {
        resultBytes[i] = (char2hex(hexBytes[i + i]) << 4) | char2hex(hexBytes[i + i + 1]);
    }

    return resultData;
}
```

decodeHexString is a category addition on NSString.

What I'm wondering is, if it's worth supporting odd lengthed hexstrings.  And if so, how should i?

**P.S.**  Ignore my debugging macros.  And I'm aware that the syntax in use in the switch statement is a GCC extension and may not compile in all compilers. Oh and the code does work as posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely worth supporting. You can start by peeling off the first digit and incrementing your initial loop index if `[hexData length] % 2` is non-zero just before the for loop in `decodeHexString`.